# add r scripts to R project and connect to Github

Tags: r, github

I am new to using Rproject and Github. I have created some .R files  .stan and .Rdata files in Rstudio.

I would like know a way how I can connect these files to a Github repository (which I have not created yet) so that I can collaborate them with others.
 Reading through https://happygitwithr.com/rstudio-git-github.html , it appears that an Rproject is required to do this.

1. how do I add the existing .R, .stan and .RData files to  a new Rproject?

Thanks

Comment: If you follow the steps at your link, creating a repo on Github and then using RStudio to clone it, you can just copy your existing files into the folder once you've cloned it. Everything should already be covered by your link. There's nothing unique about the way git/Github treats R files.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new. I recommend you install [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) and read [this](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/) if you are unfamiliar with it. log in using your GitHub credentials. Then go to File>New Repository and add your folder as a repository (you don't really need to have it as an Rproject although it is a good idea). You can simply commit everything with a message and then use "Push origin" to push it to GitHub.
Hope it helps.